# Add elements to list based on size of sublist python

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have a list of entries:

```
List X: 
[[1, 1, 'D'],
 [2, 5, 'C'],
 [6, 22, 'S'],
 [23, 57, 'C'],
 [58, 59, 'S'],
 [60, 62, 'C'],
 [63, 64, 'S'],
 [65, 76, 'C'],
 [77, 77, 'S'],
 [78, 79, 'C'],
 [80, 96, 'S'],
 [97, 105, 'C'],
 [106, 132, 'S'],
 [133, 134, 'C'],
 [135, 137, 'S'],
 [138, 150, 'C'],
 [151, 169, 'S'],
 [170, 173, 'C'],
 [174, 174, 'D']...
```

I have another list, which contains a set of integers:

```
List Y: 
[18,
 3,
 1,
 3,
 4,
 8,
 1,
 1,
 3,
 12,
 13,
 13,
 23,
 10,
 10,
 5,
 1,
 4...
```

I want to create a list z of sublists from list X based on the sizes indicated by the integers in list Y.

For example:

The first 18 entries from List X will be a sublist of list Z.
The next 3 entries from list X will be a sublist of list Z.
The next 1 entries from list X will be a sublist of list Z and so on.

So the final result will look something like:

```
List z: 

[[[1, 1, 'D'],
 [2, 5, 'C'],
 [6, 22, 'S'],
 [23, 57, 'C'],
 [58, 59, 'S'],
 [60, 62, 'C'],
 [63, 64, 'S'],
 [65, 76, 'C'],
 [77, 77, 'S'],
 [78, 79, 'C'],
 [80, 96, 'S'],
 [97, 105, 'C'],
 [106, 132, 'S'],
 [133, 134, 'C'],
 [135, 137, 'S'],
 [138, 150, 'C'],
 [151, 169, 'S'],
 [170, 173, 'C']], [[174, 174, 'D'],
 [175, 316, 'S'],
 [317, 318, 'C']], [[319, 463, 'S']]...
```

Comment: Referring sublist do you mean append all these as a element in list Z? please provide the output, show the output in which format you need.

Comment: Adding it to the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding the items iteratively to a new list:

```
X = [[1, 1, 'D'],
     [2, 5, 'C'],
     [6, 22, 'S'],
     [23, 57, 'C'],
     [58, 59, 'S'],
     [60, 62, 'C'],
     [63, 64, 'S']]
Y = [1, 2, 3]

Z, c = [], 0
for n in Y:
    Z.append(X[c: c + n])
    c += n
```